# Creating folder structure in Source control region in RTC?

Tags: rtc

Can I create a folder structure in ALM for Streams.

1. One folder for Trunk code.
2. One for tagged code.
3. One for branch.

Inside each folder the corresponding streams should be placed or grouped.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, the IBM RTC GUI does not provide hierarchy or folders for streams.

You have to use some kind of naming convention in order to identify which stream is for what, as opposed to group them in "folders" within one project.

That is illustrated in "[RTC Eclipse Client Grouping Streams in a Folder Structure](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/187721/rtc-eclipse-client-grouping-streams-in-a-folder-structure)"

> Is there anyway to group related streams into a folder structure?
>   Otherwise the list of streams will grow and be more unmanageable unlike the simple 2 streams in the attached example:

[image: streams]

The latest "[RTC Stream creation](https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.team.scm.doc%2Ftopics%2Ft_scm_eclipse_components_streams.html)" help page does not mention folder either.

Comment: @user3302323 from my practice, yes: it helps sorting the streams.

Comment: @user3302323 As usual, please review your past questions: you have a lot without accepted answers. (that is the green tick)

Comment: @user3302323 look at the list in http://stackoverflow.com/users/3302323/user3302323?tab=questions